# Undefined Reference to suart_tunedDelay in AVR Firmware Project

Tags: avr, avr-gcc, avrdude

I am getting an undefined reference error when trying to compile a c project for AVR.

When I compile this is the console output:

```
12:05:18 **** Incremental Build of configuration Release for project TimDuino ****
make all 
Building target: TimDuino.elf
Invoking: AVR C Linker
avr-gcc -Wl,-Map,TimDuino.map -mmcu=atmega328p -o "TimDuino.elf"  ./MP3sound.o ./fifo.o ./i2c.o ./main.o ./realtime.o ./sequencer.o ./serial.o ./servo.o ./suart.o ./wmath.o   
/usr/local/opt/avr-binutils/bin/avr-ld: ./suart.o: in function `suart_putc':
suart.c:(.text.suart_putc+0x28): undefined reference to `suart_tunedDelay'
/usr/local/opt/avr-binutils/bin/avr-ld: suart.c:(.text.suart_putc+0x3a): undefined reference to `suart_tx_pin_write'
/usr/local/opt/avr-binutils/bin/avr-ld: suart.c:(.text.suart_putc+0x46): undefined reference to `suart_tunedDelay'
/usr/local/opt/avr-binutils/bin/avr-ld: suart.c:(.text.suart_putc+0x52): undefined reference to `suart_tx_pin_write'
/usr/local/opt/avr-binutils/bin/avr-ld: suart.c:(.text.suart_putc+0x6c): undefined reference to `suart_tunedDelay'
/usr/local/opt/avr-binutils/bin/avr-ld: ./suart.o: in function `suart2_putc':
suart.c:(.text.suart2_putc+0x28): undefined reference to `suart_tunedDelay'
/usr/local/opt/avr-binutils/bin/avr-ld: suart.c:(.text.suart2_putc+0x3a): undefined reference to `suart2_tx_pin_write'
/usr/local/opt/avr-binutils/bin/avr-ld: suart.c:(.text.suart2_putc+0x46): undefined reference to `suart_tunedDelay'
/usr/local/opt/avr-binutils/bin/avr-ld: suart.c:(.text.suart2_putc+0x52): undefined reference to `suart2_tx_pin_write'
/usr/local/opt/avr-binutils/bin/avr-ld: suart.c:(.text.suart2_putc+0x6c): undefined reference to `suart_tunedDelay'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [TimDuino.elf] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

12:05:18 Build Failed. 11 errors, 0 warnings. (took 146ms)
```

The project has both suart.c and suart.h in the project folder and suart.h is included in main.c.

However I cannot find any declaration of the functions in either suart file.

Interestingly, if I click on the suart.c file in Eclipse and Build File, it builds fine. Its only when trying to build the project that I get the errors.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Contents of Suart.c

```
    /*
 * softuart.c
 * Software serial communication implementation
 * Does not use timers, just delays
 * For best timing compile with interrupts off (define SUART_TURN_OFF_INTERRUPTS_WHILE_TRANSMIT),
 * but at 9600 bauds with short interrupts it is not necessary
 * v1.0 - clean C code, inspired from complex arduino C++ library
 * v1.1 - correct assembly routine so it compiles in gcc 4.4
 * v1.2 - add support for 2 suart pins
 * v1.3 - switch for MarcDuino v1 and v2 Suart2 pin in header
 *
*/

/***** DEBUG of suart2
#include <stdlib.h>         // for itoa(), integer to string conversion
#include <stdio.h>          // for sprintf(), don't use if you are short on memory
*********/

#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#include "toolbox.h"
#include "suart.h"

// Delay lookup table

typedef struct _DELAY_TABLE
{
  long baud;
  unsigned short rx_delay_centering;
  unsigned short rx_delay_intrabit;
  unsigned short rx_delay_stopbit;
  unsigned short tx_delay;
} DELAY_TABLE;

// delay tables are available for 8 MHz, 16 MHz and 20 MHz clocks only
// stored in program memory to save RAM

#if F_CPU == 16000000

static const DELAY_TABLE PROGMEM suart_delay_table[] =
{
  //  baud    rxcenter   rxintra    rxstop    tx
  { 115200,   1,         17,        17,       12,    },
  { 57600,    10,        37,        37,       33,    },
  { 38400,    25,        57,        57,       54,    },
  { 31250,    31,        70,        70,       68,    },
  { 28800,    34,        77,        77,       74,    },
  { 19200,    54,        117,       117,      114,   },
  { 14400,    74,        156,       156,      153,   },
  { 9600,     114,       236,       236,      233,   },
  { 4800,     233,       474,       474,      471,   },
  { 2400,     471,       950,       950,      947,   },
  { 1200,     947,       1902,      1902,     1899,  },
  { 300,      3804,      7617,      7617,     7614,  },
};

const int XMIT_START_ADJUSTMENT = 5;

#elif F_CPU == 8000000

static const DELAY_TABLE suart_delay_table[] PROGMEM =
{
  //  baud    rxcenter    rxintra    rxstop  tx
  { 115200,   1,          5,         5,      3,      },
  { 57600,    1,          15,        15,     13,     },
  { 38400,    2,          25,        26,     23,     },
  { 31250,    7,          32,        33,     29,     },
  { 28800,    11,         35,        35,     32,     },
  { 19200,    20,         55,        55,     52,     },
  { 14400,    30,         75,        75,     72,     },
  { 9600,     50,         114,       114,    112,    },
  { 4800,     110,        233,       233,    230,    },
  { 2400,     229,        472,       472,    469,    },
  { 1200,     467,        948,       948,    945,    },
  { 300,      1895,       3805,      3805,   3802,   },
};

const int XMIT_START_ADJUSTMENT = 4;

#elif F_CPU == 20000000

// 20MHz support courtesy of the good people at macegr.com.
// Thanks, Garrett!

static const DELAY_TABLE PROGMEM suart_delay_table[] =
{
  //  baud    rxcenter    rxintra    rxstop  tx
  { 115200,   3,          21,        21,     18,     },
  { 57600,    20,         43,        43,     41,     },
  { 38400,    37,         73,        73,     70,     },
  { 31250,    45,         89,        89,     88,     },
  { 28800,    46,         98,        98,     95,     },
  { 19200,    71,         148,       148,    145,    },
  { 14400,    96,         197,       197,    194,    },
  { 9600,     146,        297,       297,    294,    },
  { 4800,     296,        595,       595,    592,    },
  { 2400,     592,        1189,      1189,   1186,   },
  { 1200,     1187,       2379,      2379,   2376,   },
  { 300,      4759,       9523,      9523,   9520,   },
};

const int XMIT_START_ADJUSTMENT = 6;

#else

#error This version of SoftUart supports only 20, 16 and 8MHz processors

#endif


// variables used by this module [NEED TO RENAME]

static uint16_t _rx_delay_centering;
static uint16_t _rx_delay_intrabit;
static uint16_t _rx_delay_stopbit;
static uint16_t _tx_delay;

// tuned delay loop
inline void suart_tunedDelay(uint16_t delay) {
  uint8_t tmp=0;

  asm volatile("sbiw    %0, 0x01 \n\t"
    "ldi %1, 0xFF \n\t"
    "cpi %A0, 0xFF \n\t"
    "cpc %B0, %1 \n\t"
    "brne .-10 \n\t"
//    : "+r" (delay), "+a" (tmp)
//  for gcc 4.4 compiler, need to use 'w' qualifier to force it to use upper registers for sbiw
//  instruction. Any register 'r' will not work with sbiw causing asm error.
    : "+w" (delay), "+a" (tmp)
    : "0" (delay)
    );
}

inline void suart_tx_pin_write(uint8_t pin_state)
{
    digitalWrite(SUART_TX_PORT, SUART_TX_PIN, pin_state);
}

// Module Init
void suart_init(long speed)
{
  _rx_delay_centering=0;
  _rx_delay_intrabit=0;
  _rx_delay_stopbit=0;
  _tx_delay=0;

  // set Tx pin for output
  digitalMode(SUART_TX_PORT, SUART_TX_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(SUART_TX_PORT, SUART_TX_PIN, HIGH);

  // read delay settings from table to match baud rate

  uint8_t i;
  for (i=0; i<sizeof(suart_delay_table)/sizeof(suart_delay_table[0]); ++i)
  {
    long baud = pgm_read_dword(&suart_delay_table[i].baud);
    if (baud == speed)
    {
      _rx_delay_centering = pgm_read_word(&suart_delay_table[i].rx_delay_centering);
      _rx_delay_intrabit = pgm_read_word(&suart_delay_table[i].rx_delay_intrabit);
      _rx_delay_stopbit = pgm_read_word(&suart_delay_table[i].rx_delay_stopbit);
      _tx_delay = pgm_read_word(&suart_delay_table[i].tx_delay);
      break;
    }
  }
}


void suart_putc(uint8_t b)
{
    uint8_t mask;

  if (_tx_delay == 0)
    return;

#ifdef SUART_TURN_OFF_INTERRUPTS_WHILE_TRANSMIT
  uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;
  cli();  // turn off interrupts for a clean txmit
#endif

  // Write the start bit
  suart_tx_pin_write(LOW);
  suart_tunedDelay(_tx_delay + XMIT_START_ADJUSTMENT);

  // Write each of the 8 bits

    for (mask = 0x01; mask; mask <<= 1)
    {
      if (b & mask) // choose bit
        suart_tx_pin_write(HIGH); // send 1
      else
        suart_tx_pin_write(LOW); // send 0

      suart_tunedDelay(_tx_delay);
    }

    suart_tx_pin_write(HIGH); // restore pin to natural state

#ifdef SUART_TURN_OFF_INTERRUPTS_WHILE_TRANSMIT
  SREG = oldSREG; // turn interrupts back on
  sei();
#endif

  suart_tunedDelay(_tx_delay);
}

void suart_puts(char* string)
{
    uint8_t i=0;
    while( (string[i]!='\0') & (i<255))
    {
        suart_putc(string[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

/*************************************************************************
suart_puts_p()
Transmit string stored in program memory (so it does not take RAM space)
String has to be declared as
#include <avr/pgmspace.h> // optional, already included in this header
const char string[] PROGMEM = "Hello World";
suart_puts_p(string);
**************************************************************************/
void suart_puts_p(const char *progmem_s )
{
    register char c;
    while ( (c = pgm_read_byte(progmem_s++)) )
      suart_putc(c);
}

// **** suart2 functions for dual port ********
#ifdef SUART_DUAL_PORT

static uint16_t _rx2_delay_centering;
static uint16_t _rx2_delay_intrabit;
static uint16_t _rx2_delay_stopbit;
static uint16_t _tx2_delay;

inline void suart2_tx_pin_write(uint8_t pin_state)
{
    digitalWrite(SUART2_TX_PORT, SUART2_TX_PIN, pin_state);
}

// Module Init
void suart2_init(long speed)
{
  _rx2_delay_centering=0;
  _rx2_delay_intrabit=0;
  _rx2_delay_stopbit=0;
  _tx2_delay=0;

  // set Tx pin for output
  digitalMode(SUART2_TX_PORT, SUART2_TX_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(SUART2_TX_PORT, SUART2_TX_PIN, HIGH);

  // read delay settings from table to match baud rate

  uint8_t i;
  for (i=0; i<sizeof(suart_delay_table)/sizeof(suart_delay_table[0]); ++i)
  {
    long baud = pgm_read_dword(&suart_delay_table[i].baud);
    if (baud == speed)
    {
      _rx2_delay_centering = pgm_read_word(&suart_delay_table[i].rx_delay_centering);
      _rx2_delay_intrabit = pgm_read_word(&suart_delay_table[i].rx_delay_intrabit);
      _rx2_delay_stopbit = pgm_read_word(&suart_delay_table[i].rx_delay_stopbit);
      _tx2_delay = pgm_read_word(&suart_delay_table[i].tx_delay);
      break;
    }
  }

  /**** debug
  suart2_puts("\r\nsuart2 output test\r\n");
  char string[64];
  sprintf(string, "PORT: %2d PIN: %2d \r\n", SUART2_TX_PORT, SUART2_TX_PIN);
  suart2_puts(string);
  ***********/
}


void suart2_putc(uint8_t b)
{
    uint8_t mask;

  if (_tx2_delay == 0)
    return;

#ifdef SUART_TURN_OFF_INTERRUPTS_WHILE_TRANSMIT
  uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;
  cli();  // turn off interrupts for a clean txmit
#endif

  // Write the start bit
  suart2_tx_pin_write(LOW);
  suart_tunedDelay(_tx2_delay + XMIT_START_ADJUSTMENT);

  // Write each of the 8 bits

    for (mask = 0x01; mask; mask <<= 1)
    {
      if (b & mask) // choose bit
        suart2_tx_pin_write(HIGH); // send 1
      else
        suart2_tx_pin_write(LOW); // send 0

      suart_tunedDelay(_tx2_delay);
    }

    suart2_tx_pin_write(HIGH); // restore pin to natural state

#ifdef SUART_TURN_OFF_INTERRUPTS_WHILE_TRANSMIT
  SREG = oldSREG; // turn interrupts back on
  sei();
#endif

  suart_tunedDelay(_tx2_delay);
}

void suart2_puts(char* string)
{
    uint8_t i=0;
    while( (string[i]!='\0') & (i<255))
    {
        suart2_putc(string[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

void suart2_puts_p(const char *progmem_s )
{
    register char c;
    while ( (c = pgm_read_byte(progmem_s++)) )
      suart2_putc(c);
}




#endif
```

And of Suart.h

```
/*
 * suart.c
 * Software serial communication implementation
 *
 * Turns a regular I/O pin into a serial output
 *
 * In order to preserve hardware timers for other uses, this uses calibrated delays
 * For best timing compile with interrupts off (define SUART_TURN_OFF_INTERRUPTS_WHILE_TRANSMIT),
 * but at 9600 bauds with short interrupts it does not matter
 *
 * Created July 7, 2012
 * Author: Marc Verdiell
 * Inspired in part by Arduino NewSoftSerial library
 *
 */

#ifndef suart_h
#define suart_h

#include <avr/pgmspace.h>   // for reading strings from program memory
#include "main.h"           // for the _MARCDUINOV2_ compile flag

#ifndef GCC_VERSION
#define GCC_VERSION (__GNUC__ * 10000 + __GNUC_MINOR__ * 100 + __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__)
#endif

#ifndef F_CPU
/* prevent compiler error by supplying a 16 MHz default */
# warning "F_CPU not defined for <suart.h>"
# define F_CPU 16000000UL
#endif


// for very high baud rates you might need to uncomment this for precise timing.
// It will turn off interrupts while transmitting on the software UART.
// But at 9600 bauds no need to do this if running interrupt handlers are fast enough

#define SUART_TURN_OFF_INTERRUPTS_WHILE_TRANSMIT


// comment the following line out if you only need one SUART port
#define SUART_DUAL_PORT


//****** first default port **********
// Put your Tx pin location here
// SUART is Slave output
#define SUART_TX_PIN    0
#define SUART_TX_PORT   PORTC

// just three functions needed for writing
void suart_init(long baudrate);
void suart_putc(uint8_t b);
void suart_puts(char* string);
void suart_puts_p(const char *progmem_s );

//*********second optional port ******
#ifdef SUART_DUAL_PORT

//Suart 2 is MP3/Teeces Out
    #ifdef _MARCDUINOV2_ // Marcduino V2 board has PC1 as SUART2
        #define SUART2_TX_PIN   1
        #define SUART2_TX_PORT  PORTC
    #else               // Marcduino V1 board has PC4 as SUART2
        #define SUART2_TX_PIN   4
        #define SUART2_TX_PORT  PORTC
    #endif

#endif

//PC2 == AUX1 == Suart3???

void suart2_init(long baudrate);
void suart2_putc(uint8_t b);
void suart2_puts(char* string);
void suart2_puts_p(const char *progmem_s );

#endif
```

Comment: I've never seen usage of `inline` on function without `static`. Try to add `static` to the definition of `suart_tunedDelay`

Comment: AterLux - tried adding static, no luck. Tried changing to just a void definition and no luck either. It looks like the problem may be in linking with gcc?

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that avr-gcc is not inlining `suart_tunedDelay` and also is not generating code for it.

GCC supported `inline` as part of GNU-C before its adopion by C99, and due to that the semantics of `(extern) inline` underwent sublle changes in semantics, see for example GCC's [documentation of `inline`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html).

You can request additional diagnostics by means of `-Winline`, but presumably that will just tell you that the function was not inlined because the compiler thinks it would increase code size (and optimization is `-Os`, i.e. for code size).

As the function is just few instructions from inline assembly, the simplest fix is to make it static (it's internal to the module because not declared in the header) and always inline like in:

```c
static inline __attribute__((__always_inline__))
void suart_tunedDelay (uint16_t delay)
{
    ...
```

---

As an aside, the constraints of the respective inline assembly can be relaxed from

```c
    : "+w" (delay), "+a" (tmp)
    : "0" (delay));
```

to

```c
    : "+w" (delay), "=d" (tmp));
```

which gives the register allocator more freedom for the allocation of `tmp`.  Moreover, there's no need to initialize `tmp=0` because that value is never used, hence `=d` instead of `+a`.